# Scale Leaflet container to increase performance, issues with calculations

Tags: javascript, html, css, leaflet, css-transforms

I have a full-screen map that is suffering from some performance issues, due many markers (I'm using Mark Cluster already, wonderful plugin) and the size of it. Then I tought of experimenting with the size.

If I shrink the container size by half, and then by CSS3 scale it up twice as big again, I get a huge performance boost! Much like the ol' HTML% Canvas trick (scale it up by CSS). Like this:

```
/* Before */
#map {
    width:1000px;
    height:400px;
}

/* After */
#map {
    width: 500px;
    height:200px;
    -webkit-transform: scale(2,2);
    ...
}
```

However, now the calculations is a bit screwed. For example `setZoomAround()` calculates wrong point, and pinch-zoom is iffy on mobiles. Also panning is too quick (since its moving twice the speed).

I tried to tweak this myself, but am not very involved in the mechanics under the hood in Leaflet. Somewhere I need to counteract this scale by 2, does anyone know this better than me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out all you have to do is divide the mouse X/Y position in the events, by your scalar. So `e.clientX` with a sclar of `2`, would be `e.clientX/2`.

Hope that helps someone!